# Unity3D - Show a custom list on the Inspector

Tags: list, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I have a simple EventList that I want to show on the Inspector.

```
public class EventList<T> : List<T> 
{
    public GenericEvent<T> OnAdd;

    public new void Add(T item)
    {
        base.Add(item);
        OnAdd.Invoke(item);
    }
}

public class GenericEvent<T> : UnityEvent<T> { }
```

How do I show this on the Inspector similar to how a List is shown, using the simplest way possible, without the use of 3rd-party assets? Thanks!

Comment: Unity is not able to serialize generics. You will need to create classes inheriting from `EventList` and `GenericEvent` and specify the type `T`. You will also need to replace `OnAdd` variable by a Getter and override this getter in the subclasses.

Comment: @Hellium Unity can show normal lists with any types (like a `List<ExampleObj>` for example) on the Inspector though. Shouldn't it be possible to do this too?

Comment: Well, `List` are the exception to the rule ! 
Take a look at [this page of the manual](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-Serialization.html). **`Container field types that can be serialized :`** `An array of a simple field type that can be serialized ; A List<T> of a simple field type that can be serialized` **`How to ensure a custom class can be serialized`** `Ensure it: Is not generic, though it may inherit from a generic class`

Comment: You will have to create custom inspector for this. It just depends do you really need it. If you do there is documentation how you can do it.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUILayout.html